# decrypt in Linux string encrypted in PowerShell

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, encryption, openssl

I have following PowerShell commands

```
$a = 'MySecret'
$b = 'MySecretKey4Test'
$c = ConvertTo-SecureString $a -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key ($b.ToCharArray() | % {[byte]$_})
```

Briefly, I am encrypting $a using $b as key. How can I decrypt resulting string $c under Linux, for example using openssl?

I tried these things

```
$b | out-file 'b.txt' -enc ascii
$c | out-file 'c.txt' -enc ascii
```

Then in same folder, I tried

```
openssl enc -d -aes128 -in c.txt -kfile b.txt
```

But it fails with *"bad magic number"* :(

Comment: [openssl: recover key and IV by passphrase](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/29106/29925) on [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is 4 years old, but it still came up at the top of my search results when I went looking for the same thing, and with no answer.

Here's the answer.

First use your script to create an encrypted string:

```
$a = 'MySecret'
$b = 'MySecretKey4Test'
$c = ConvertTo-SecureString $a -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key ($b.ToCharArray() | % {[byte]$_})
```

Let's get our b (key) and c (encrypted string) into bash to begin with:

```
b="MySecretKey4Test"
c="76492d1116743f0423413b16050a5345MgB8ADkATgB4AEgAMQBZAHAAdABYAGgASgBJAGoAWABIAFMARgBoAHEANABhAHcAPQA9AHwAOABhADYANgBkAGUAZQBhAGIAMQBiADcANAA4ADMAZgA5AGUAYwA2ADEAZQBiADYAZAA5AGYAMgBmAGMAYgBmAGEANQBhADgAOAA4AGEAYgBhAGIAMgBiADAAYQA4AGYAMwBhAGYANwAyADUAYgA1AGMANgA4ADQAZQBjADgAMAA="
```

We need to convert the key to hexadecimal, being careful not to get a newline at the end.

```
read -r b < <(echo -n "$b"|xxd -p -c 9999)
```

We need to remove a fixed header from the beginning of the encrypted string.  The fixed header is always `76492d1116743f0423413b16050a5345`.  Not sure why this is here, but it is.

```
c="${c/76492d1116743f0423413b16050a5345/}"
```

Next up, decode the encrypted string as base64 and pass it through iconv, to properly parse the utf16-le characters.  Then split the result on `|` into an array (called `parts` here).

```
IFS='|' read -r -a parts < <(base64 -d <<< "$c"|iconv -f UTF16LE -co - -)
```

`parts[0]` is just a part count, which will be `2` and can be ignored.
`parts[1]` is the cbc initialization vector in base64 format, but openssl wants it in hexadecimal.

```
read -r iv < <(base64 -d <<< "${parts[1]}"|xxd -p -c 99999)
```

`parts[2]` is the actual encrypted data in hexadecimal format.

```
read -r crypt <<< "${parts[2]}"
```

Now we decrypt, using the key ($b), iv ($iv) and encrypted data ($crypt).
$crypt will need to be converted to binary first, so we use xxd.

```
read -r decrypted < <(openssl enc -d -A -aes-128-cbc -iv "$iv" -K "$b" < <(xxd -r -p <<< "$crypt"))
echo "$decrypted"
```

All together now:

```
b="MySecretKey4Test"
c="76492d1116743f0423413b16050a5345MgB8ADkATgB4AEgAMQBZAHAAdABYAGgASgBJAGoAWABIAFMARgBoAHEANABhAHcAPQA9AHwAOABhADYANgBkAGUAZQBhAGIAMQBiADcANAA4ADMAZgA5AGUAYwA2ADEAZQBiADYAZAA5AGYAMgBmAGMAYgBmAGEANQBhADgAOAA4AGEAYgBhAGIAMgBiADAAYQA4AGYAMwBhAGYANwAyADUAYgA1AGMANgA4ADQAZQBjADgAMAA="
read -r b < <(echo -n "$b"|xxd -p -c 9999)
c="${c/76492d1116743f0423413b16050a5345/}"
IFS='|' read -r -a parts < <(base64 -d <<< "$c"|iconv -f UTF16LE -co - -)
read -r iv < <(base64 -d <<< "${parts[1]}"|xxd -p -c 99999)
read -r crypt <<< "${parts[2]}"
read -r decrypted < <(openssl enc -d -A -aes-128-cbc -iv "$iv" -K "$b" < <(xxd -r -p <<< "$crypt"))
echo "$decrypted"
```

Results:

```
MySecret
```

Be aware that if you use a 32-byte (256bit) key instead of a 16-byte (128bit) key, use `-aes-256-cbc` in your openssl command instead of `-aes-128-cbc`